# Cannot save a freshly created bmp file, help needed

Tags: vb.net

Hate to sound like a broken record, but I simply cannot get the program I wrote in Visual Basic to write a file when run standalone; but it works fine when run via the debugger.

Simplified, the code looks like this (and the bitmap image is being created and is being saved, i.e., the file does not already exist):

```
Using bmp As New Bitmap(imgHorSize, imgVerSize) ‘ the sizes are not too large
  <build the bitmap>
  Dim fName As String = “C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\temp\foobar.jpg"
  bmp.Save(fName, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
End Using
```

When I run this outside the debugger, I get

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
> 'C:\Users<name>\Desktop\temp\foobar.jpg' is denied

I saw some notes that suggest there should be a \\ after C:. Other sources show using a / instead of a \. Not sure that either really matters (since the directory name is coming from the result of a FolderBrowserDialog). I have checked the folder permissions on temp and see that my account has full control. I added user Everyone, via the security tab, and gave it full control. Same problem. As an experiment, I changed the above code to

```
Using bmp As New Bitmap(imgHorSize, imgVerSize)
  <build the bitmap>
  Dim fName As String = “C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\temp\foobar.jpg"
  Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
  file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(fName, True)
  file.WriteLine("Here is the first string.")
End Using
```

and I got the exact same error. I also tried creating a MemoryStream, but that also didn’t work.

So, the issue is probably not related to the bmp.Save process, but something more fundamental. I have been looking at various things and have tried a few of them, but nothing works. This should be super easy to do, so what am I doing wrong?

== follow up ==

To come up with something to share in its entirety, I just wrote the following, very simple  program that basically does the same as the real program:

```
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Drawing.Imaging

Public Class Form1
    Structure myImages
        Dim strFName As String
        Dim imgL As Image
    End Structure

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim imgLI As myImages
        imgLI.strFName = "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\EinRiddle\ItemImages\An_Cat.jpg"
        imgLI.imgL = New Bitmap(Image.FromFile(imgLI.strFName), 150, 150)

        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(300, 400)
        Using bmp
            Dim gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            gr.Clear(Color.WhiteSmoke)
            gr.DrawImage(imgLI.imgL, 20, 20)

            bmp.Save("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\testImg.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            gr.Dispose()
        End Using
        Application.Exit()
        End
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am getting the same error message...

Comment: When asking a question about code, it is always necessary to add a tag for the language you're using. It's also not helpful to add meaningless tags like *save* and *bmp*, because they don't add any value whatsoever. I've edited your post accordingly.

Comment: Does it work with `Dim fName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "foobar.jpg"))`?

Comment: With regard to the suggestion about using Path.Combine: I just added the line shown to the above test program  (and replaced the hard-wired filename with fname) and got the same error.

Comment: @GRoston Is the value of `fTemp` what you expect it to be? You could use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) (probably add a filter for the filename) to see who is trying to write it to what location.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried another directory? Often one cannot write a file to the desktop.
2. Have you tried another format (for example `ImageFormat.Bmp`)?
3. You use “ instead of **"** ... Is that the mistake? Ah, I guess this is not the real code and you wrote this from memory and and something made “
4. Sometimes it takes a while before the picture and graphics can be disposed because the image is saved lazily. Even if this is not welcomed, give it a try

```
            bmp.Save("C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\testImg.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            Application.DoEvents()
            gr.Dispose()
        End Using
```

Comment: Daniel - I have created an even more simplified version of this program that generates the exact same error. In this version, I tried your suggestions 1, 2, and 4 - same error each time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: On this computer, my user files are on the D: drive. Thus, when I changed the path from C: to D:, it worked. Of course, why this is necessary, since there is symbolic link, I don't understand...

Comment: Just to check, does `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` give the correct location? (Note: `.DesktopDirectory` instead of `.Desktop`.)